# Change color of labels on x-axis of a Google Chart timeline view

Tags: google-visualization

I'm trying to change the color of the black labels on the x-axis.  Now they're black, which don't go well with the background.  In the documentation I only found: rowLabelStyle or barLabelStyle.  How can I change the color of the labels on the x-axis?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By using this CSS:

```
#timeline text {
  fill: #dddada; 
}
```

The text appears light.